# Falta cadena conexión en Control de usuario c#

Tags: c#

hola tengo un problema que al agregar algunos controles de usuario a mi formulario la vista de diseño de este se rompe, pero a pesar de ello compila el proyecto y los controles se muestran en el formulario, permitiendo operar con estos e interactuar con la BD.

> Esta linea del Main.Designer.cs es la que rompe la vista de diseño
>
> ```
> this.Controls.Add(this.panel_contenido); //contiene los controles de usuario
> ```

Mensaje de error:

> No se encuentra ninguna cadena de conexión denominada 'SistemaPacientesEntities' en el archivo de configuración de la aplicación.

Mi duda es ¿por qué dice que no encuentra la cadena conexión y cuando compila, a pesar de este problema, trabaja perfectamente con los datos de la BD (todas las operaciones de un ABM básico las realiza correctamente) a través de los controles mencionados?

Comment: Debes añadir el código para que podamos darte una buena respuesta. Intenta poner el código que puedas para poder ver que es `'SistemaPacientesEntities'`.

Comment: @Marc ahora agrego el app.config donde tengo definido la cadena de conexion, SIstemaPacientesEntities es el nombre que le di a la cadena de conexion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema fue solucionado haciendo uso de un truco, lo que ocurría era que se quería conectar a la BD en tiempos de diseño y no encontraba la cadena conexión es por eso que hago uso de esto:

```
   private void UserControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.DesignMode)
        {
            //codigo
        }

    }
```

> Aclaración: Esto no funciona para UserControl anidados, es decir si se pone un User Control dentro de otro este planteo no va a funcionar